# Get all numbers that appears k times consecutively in a matrix in java

Tags: java, algorithm

This is extension with more details to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677573/get-all-numbers-that-appears-k-times-in-matrix) as it is marked as closed.

I have a matrix of size `nxn`, now I want to find an number that occurs k times consecutively (top, bottom, left, right, diagonal). If number found then return it otherwise return 0. If there are multiple numbers that are occurring k times return all of them in ascending order.

```
Example:

Given matrix:

3 5 3 9 5
4 3 2 1 8
9 4 3 1 9
8 4 7 6 4
1 2 5 9 1

Given k = 3

Output: number 3. Because only number 3 is occurring 3 times in diagonal way.
```

How to write this logic in Java programming. Can you please give some idea so I can proceed from there?
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] m = { { 3, 5, 3, 9, 5 }, { 4, 3, 2, 1, 8 }, { 9, 4, 3, 1, 9 }, { 8, 4, 7, 6, 4 }, { 1, 2, 5, 9, 1 } };
int k = 3;

```
    List<Integer> result = process(m, k);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static List<Integer> process(int[][] m, int k) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            int count = map.getOrDefault(m[i][j], 0);
            map.put(m[i][j], count + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int number : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(number) >= k) {
            int consecutiveCount = getConsecutiveCount(number, m, k);
            if (consecutiveCount >= k) {
                result.add(number);
            }
        }
    }
    if (result.size() == 0) {
        result.add(-1);
    }
    return result;
}

private static int getConsecutiveCount(int number, int[][] m, int k) {
    return 0;
}
```

How to implement `getConsecutiveCount` logic here?

**Update:**

Tried further to navigate adjacent nodes using below code using DFS, but the counts are not working properly, it just shows how many times a number appear in matrix:

```
static boolean isSafe(int M[][], int row, int col, boolean visited[][], int number) {
    int ROW = M.length;
    int COL = M[0].length;
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0) && (col < COL) && (M[row][col] == number && !visited[row][col]);
}

static void DFS(int M[][], int row, int col, boolean visited[][], int number, int[] total) {
    int rowNbr[] = new int[] {-1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    int colNbr[] = new int[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 1};

    visited[row][col] = true;
    total[0]++;
    for (int k = 0; k < rowNbr.length; ++k)
        if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited, number)) {
            DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited, number, total);
        }
}

static int countIslands(int M[][], int number) {
    int ROW = M.length;
    int COL = M[0].length;
    boolean visited[][] = new boolean[ROW][COL];

    int count = 0;
    int[] total = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
            if (M[i][j] == number && !visited[i][j]) // If a cell with
            { 
                DFS(M, i, j, visited, number, total);
                ++count;
            }

    return total[0];
}

// Driver method
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int M[][] = new int[][] { { 3, 5, 3, 9, 5 }, { 4, 3, 2, 1, 8 }, { 9, 4, 3, 1, 9 }, { 8, 4, 7, 6, 4 },
            { 1, 2, 5, 9, 1 } };
    List<Integer> result = process(M, 3);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static List<Integer> process(int[][] m, int k) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            int count = map.getOrDefault(m[i][j], 0);
            map.put(m[i][j], count + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);

    for (int number : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(number) >= k) {
            int consecutiveCount = getConsecutiveCount(number, m, k);
            System.out.println(number + " : " + consecutiveCount);
            if (consecutiveCount >= k) {
                result.add(number);
            }
        }
    }
    if (result.size() == 0) {
        result.add(-1);
    }
    return result;
}

private static int getConsecutiveCount(int number, int[][] m, int k) {
    return countIslands(m, number);
}
```

Comment: Your previous question was closed because you haven't stated the issues you had when trying to implement it yourself. It needs more focus, a specific problem. All you've essentially done is posted your assignment.

Comment: You can edit questions... there's a link above these comments, to the left of your name card. You should either edit your old question and delete this one, or delete this one and edit your old question. Editing is probably the better solution because it would give you a chance to remove the downvote it received. Consider your edit carefully, because it seems you're making the same mistake in this question as you're making in the original. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're unsure.

Comment: @Dioxin, I added my code now which is using DFS approach, but got stuck on how to navigate and get the count.

Comment: So, DFS isn't quite the right approach since you don't really have an "end" of the search. I would make a method that accepts an array of size K that returns true if all elements are the same. Then I would loop over the matrix M in sections of K size (left, down, down-right, down-left) with `x = 0 < x < N-K` and `y = 0 < y < N-K`. Maybe even breaking each matrix scanning direction into its own method. I don't think you need a boolean matrix, but maybe a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` to store data "in ascending order"

Comment: Can you give one more test case

Answer (score 0):

Without actually writing this code for you, I'll point you in the right direction. The idea is to divide the problem into smaller problems until you're left with something bite-sized.

So think of it like this:

1. There are `n * n` possible starting positions. So think of that as an outer pair of nested loops over rows and columns: `y` from 0 to `n` and `x` from 0 to `n`.
2. For each starting position `x,y`, there are 8 different directions for your sequence. Think of those as two more nested loops: `dx` over -1 to 1 and `dy` over -1 to 1 (but `dx` and `dy` are not both 0).
3. For any starting position `x`, `y` (where `0`≤`x`<`n` and `0`≥`y`≤`n`, a direction vector `dx`, `dy` (where `dx` and `dy` are each **-1**, **0**, or **1** but both are not 0), you can find out if a repeated sequence of length `k` exists by comparing the value `m[x][y]` with each value `m[x+dx*i][y+dy*i]`, for values of `i` between `0` and `k`. (So there's another loop there.)

That's the whole algorithm.

Now some simplifications and boundary constraints:

1. Since a repeated sequence is by definition palindromic (the same backward as forward), you only need to consider four of those eight directions. For example: (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, 1).
2. Don't try to read any matrix values with indices that are out of range.

Happy coding!

Comment: I added my attempt based on your comments, but got stuck again, can you please check it once

Comment: There are actually `(n-k) * (n-k)` starting positions. Otherwise, you'd find the same sequences more than once (forwards and backwards). If you limit to that, then vectors are only (0,1), (1, 0), (1,1), and you'd never go "out of bounds"

Comment: That’s why you only want to look in four of the eight directions. (See my comment about palindromes)

Comment: Can you code it?

Answer (score 0):

```
input1 = int(input())  # 5
input2 = input()  # '{ { 3, 5, 3, 9, 5 }, { 4, 3, 2, 1, 8 }, { 9, 4, 3, 1, 9 }, { 8, 4, 7, 6, 4 }, { 1, 2, 5, 9, 1 } }'
input3 = int(input())  # 3
digits = [int(i) for i in input2 if i.isdigit()]
reformatted_input2 = [digits[:i+1][-5:] for i in range(len(digits)) if (i + 1) % 5 == 0]
indexes = [i.index(input3) for i in reformatted_input2 if input3 in i]
if indexes == list(range(min(indexes), max(indexes) + 1)):
    print(len(indexes))
else:
    print(-1)
```